Reference for property of $\psi_4$ of Newman-Penrose formalism
It is known that the real and imaginary part of the Newman-Penrose scalar $\psi_4$ depend on the plus and cross components of the gravitational wave.
Is there a reference where this property is proved?

If you are only interested in this property, you can simply have a look at this section on Wikipedia. Basically, you use the fact that in empty space the Weyl tensor $C_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}$ coincides with the Riemann tensor $R_{\alpha \beta\gamma \delta}$. Then, since linearized gravitational waves are related to components of the Riemann tensor, within few steps you can show that $$
\psi_4 = -\ddot{h}_+ + i\ddot{h}_\times
$$
Otherwise, if you want to know more, I suggest you have a look at the references listed at the end of the article, which cover in detail both mathematical and physical aspects of NP formalism.

In vacuum we have $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ and therefore $C_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}=R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ and so
\begin{align}
\Psi_4
&=C_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}\tilde{k}^\alpha \bar{\tilde{m}}^\beta \tilde{k}^\mu \bar{\tilde{m}}^\nu\\
&=R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}\tilde{k}^\alpha \bar{\tilde{m}}^\beta \tilde{k}^\mu \bar{\tilde{m}}^\nu\\
&=\frac{2}{i}R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}k^\alpha m^\beta k^\mu m^\nu
\end{align}
using the (rescaled) tetrad vectors
\begin{align}
\mathbf{k}&=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{e}_t-\mathbf{e}_r)\\
\tilde{\mathbf{k}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{e}_t-\mathbf{e}_r)\\
\mathbf{m}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{e}_\theta+\mathbf{e}_\phi+i(\mathbf{e}_\theta-\mathbf{e}_\phi)\right)\\
\tilde{\mathbf{m}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{e}_\theta+i\mathbf{e}_\phi)\\
\tilde{\bar{\mathbf{m}}}&=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\mathbf{m}
\end{align}
Relevant components of the Riemann tensor for the linearised wave
\begin{align}
R_{TxTx}&=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_T^2h_+\\
R_{TyTy}&=+\frac{1}{2}\partial_T^2h_+\\
R_{TxTy}&=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_T^2h_\times
\end{align}
Then we just calculate and hope - thankfully the sixty terms reduce to
\begin{align}
R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}k^\alpha m^\beta k^\mu m^\nu
&=R_{TxTy}+\frac{i}{2}(R_{TxTx}-R_{TyTy})\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_T^2h_\times-\frac{i}{2}\partial_T^2h_+
\end{align}
and obtain
\begin{align}
\Psi_4
&=\frac{2}{i}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\partial_T^2h_\times-\frac{i}{2}\partial_T^2h_+\right)\\
&=-\partial_T^2h_+ +i\partial_T^2h_\times
\end{align}
